# Asymptotic Estimate for integer division

Tags: c++, c, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

```
k = n; //integer division
while(k > 1) {
    std::cout << k; 
    k=k/2;
}
```

I need to find out the asymptotic estimate as a function of n.

Comment: And the question is....?

Comment: The question is that i need the asymptotic estimate of that function.

Comment: @user2340034: And I need to eat, otherwise I will die of starvation. The previous sentence I wrote isn't a question, it is a statement, and neither is what you have written twice. Please edit this to ask a question that someone else can answer. Code + "I need something" isn't a valid Stack Overflow question.

Comment: @talonmies: Do you honestly think that it makes a big difference to phrase something as: "What is XXX?" instead of "I need XXX."? I find it insulting to be treated like a brainless compiler that can only recognize a question if precisely the correct syntax and punctuation are used.

Comment: Actually, the primary problem here is that “asymptotic estimate” is not a clear term. On the face of it, it appears to refer to the value of a function, not the computational complexity of an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

The complexity is logarithmic.

Assuming K is non-negative, division by two is equivalent to shifting right by one bit. Therefore, the maximum number of iterations before `k` becomes 0 is the number of bits in `k`. More specifically, the position of the most significant bit in `k` that is set (i.e., a `1`) will determine the number of iterations executed in the loop.

Since the operations in the loop are (presumably) constant complexity, logarithmic number of iterations leads directly to logarithmic complexity.

Comment: Isn't it funny how *thinking* about the question yields an answer?